# lodash/fp - How to augment typescript types from @types/lodash?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, lodash

I'm trying to change the typings of `_.keys` function in `lodash/fp`.

Original type looks like this: `type LodashKeys = (object: any) => string[];`

I've tried doing this:

```js
// src/types/global.d.ts
import _ from 'lodash/fp';
declare module 'lodash/fp' {
  interface LodashKeysNew {
    <T>(object: T): (keyof T)[];
  }

  interface LoDashFp {
    keys: LodashKeysNew;
  }
}
```

But when I hover `_.keys` in VSCode it still shows the original typings.

[image]

I can Ctrl+Click the `_.keys` and I can see that it refers to my augmented type:

[image]

But it still doesn't work. Doesn't affect typechecking, still uses the original types. I have tried a lot of different things and I can't seem to make it work. I successfully augmented several other libraries, but lodash is somehow weird.

Comment: This is awful.  Your method gives an error `Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'keys' must be of type 'LodashKeys'` and when I try to overwrite the `LodashKeys` directly I get an error `Duplicate identifier 'LodashKeys'.`

Comment: For what it's worth, I have no issue doing this for the main lodash package.  ```declare module "lodash" {  interface LoDashStatic { keys<T>(object: T): (keyof T)[]; } }``` It's the fp setup that is making it a nightmare.

Comment: Yeah it seems you can't add overloads to lodash/fp functions that are defined as types. Only for those that are defined as interfaces.